# mysqli update not updating although no error

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to adapt my code, which works in a SELECT, to perform an UPDATE. Here, there is no error, but it does not update anything, it even does not even enter the loop. It is supposed to update the room type for the chosen days (`$value`).

I echoed all values to check them up and they are correct.

```
$bdd = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'webpage')
$roomty = 1;                                                                                        
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}

foreach ($_SESSION['datesBooked_1_month'] as $key => $value)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($bdd);
    if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt , "UPDATE '".$_SESSION['tab_from_month_year']."'
SET '".$_SESSION['roomtype_x']."'='".$_SESSION['roomtype_x']."' + ? WHERE day = ?"))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt ,'is', $roomty , $value );
        mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        echo " Booked !<br /> "; 
    }           
}
```

Comment: `it even does not even enter the loop` then `$_SESSION['datesBooked_1_month']` is empty for reasons outside the code you are showing, no?

Comment: I notice a missing `;` in the first line.

Comment: @pekka var_dump($_SESSION['datesBooked_1_month']) gives me right values

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes right, but it's just missing here, did not forget it in my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out, the problem was the **single quotes** before the double quotes. It seems to be working very well with only double quotes like this :

```
if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt ,  "UPDATE ".$_SESSION['tab_from_month_year']." SET  ".$_SESSION['roomtype_x']." = ".$_SESSION['roomtype_x']." + ?  WHERE  day = ?"))
```

Comment: Yeah. It's indeed "single quotes before the double quotes" yet another magical chant to be learned.

Comment: @Your Common Sense   I am not sure of what you mean, but I was saying that it is working ok now WITHOUT SINGLE QUOTES. i.e. : since I deleted them.

Comment: @SunnyOne if that's your answer, then validate it. Anyway, you should use ` ` ` (backtick) instead of single quote or "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code with the new MySql driver of PHP.

- you put the quote for a integer value, that is wrong
- do you named column with numbers? That is not comfortable.
- Are you sure that *$value* is a string?
- Why did you use *$key => $value* in the **foreach** loop?

Here the code:

```
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=webpage;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'dbpass'; #put here yor password

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

foreach $_SESSION['datesBooked_1_month'] as  $value) {
    #I hope that following variables don't contain space
    $query = "UPDATE " .$_SESSION['tab_from_month_year']; 
    $temp = $_SESSION['roomtype_x'] + $roomty ;
    #you wrote that $value is a string, are you sure?
    $query .= " SET ".$_SESSION['roomtype_x']. "=$temp WHERE day='$value'"   ;
    $dbh->query($query);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If this is the full code you need to select a database, currently the statement is being sent to the server but not to any database, there for you get no errors. You should use:

```
mysqli_select_db("You database goes here");
```

Comment: Syntax of connecting to a MySQL database using mysqli: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");`

Comment: @ aliasm2k I am in procedural style not OOP

Comment: You can use $mysqli = mysqli_connect("mysql9.000webhost.com","a5869705_test","cycling1"); And then use mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "a5869705_test");